# Qt app with dynamic set of functionalities

Tags: c++, qt

Please let me present the idea. I would like to build a Qt app which allows the user to load functionality from a external file (.dll ?) while the app is running. The file could be downloaded from the internet.

I'm planning to build the user interface with [`QUiLoader`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/quiloader.html) and I think the functionality should come from such an external file. Does it make sense?

As an example, to begin with, I'm imagining to provide the user simple functionality like sum and multiplication. And other functionality should be provided afterwards.

Since I have no ideia where to begin (as the question might suggest), I'm here to ask for directions?

Comment: This may be a starting point - there are lots of places you can learn about DLL's https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx

Comment: The word you're looking for is "plugin."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you need is a plugin mechanism.

For developing a plugin, you should decide how those plugin to be load and to get information from plugin, i.e. you should define a interface first hand, by that interface, your program can communicate with plugins developed by others.